# Ask Ubuntu Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place…

If you're a moderator on the main site, would you be interested in having your own Ask Ubuntu contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local Ubuntu meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

<sub>(click on image to see full res version)</sub>

[image: Ask Ubuntu Moderator Cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the look alone - spectacular.

Comment: Wow Keyser Söze has an account at ask ubuntu thats awesome.......

Answer (score 7):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 6):

I'd find it really cool to own but I don't know where I'd give them out. It makes sense if you're an employee who needs a professional hand-me-out.

Has this been done for any other sites' moderators? How are they using them?

I'm not against the idea - they look great.

Comment: We have made similar posts on other SE meta sites. From personal experience, I didn't think I'd ever pass out cards. But once I got my cards I've found myself passing them around a lot more. I guess it's one of those things that once you have it, you'll see the opportunity to give them out. Of course, this really varies from person to person.

Comment: we can also make them conditionally for people going to conferences -- even if they're not moderators -- per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/ just sell us on the idea!

Comment: I personally wear Ubuntu items all the time and get stopped by Ubuntu users who recognize the logo, or by people curious what it is. Having a business card which I can supply them to drive traffic to the site would be great!

Comment: @Marco That's great. I need more Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu clothing. **Wink**.